# Next.js layout strange behavior

Tags: javascript, next.js, nav, next.js13

I have no idea of why that happens, I have a layout with my navbar, but when I refresh the page the navbar blink in the screen and fade away.

My app dir tree:

```
.
├── actions.tsx
├── api
│   └── test
│       └── route.ts
├── globals.css
├── layout.tsx
└── page.tsx
```

In layout.tsx:

```
import "./globals.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Link from "next/link";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Blachere CRM",
  description: "Blachere CRM by Jonathan Lauxen Romano",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  type NavItem = {
    title: string;
    path: string;
  };

  const navigation: NavItem[] = [
    {
      title: "Home",
      path: "/",
    },
    {
      title: "Contacts",
      path: "/contacts",
    },
    {
      title: "Proposals",
      path: "/newProposal",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <nav className="bg-blue-500 text-white h-12 flex items-center justify-center gap-12">
        {navigation.map((navItem) => (
          <Link key={navItem.title} href={navItem.path}>
            <div>{navItem.title}</div>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </nav>

      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

And in page.tsx:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <text>test</text>
    </main>
  )
}
```

After the blink, I got the following errors:

```
Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <nav> in <html>.
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

I tried paste the same code on other page(contacts) and works well:

```
.
├── actions.tsx
├── api
│   └── teste
│       └── route.ts
├── contacts
│   ├── layout.tsx
│   └── page.tsx
├── globals.css
├── layout.tsx
└── page.tsx
```

So what am I doing wrong? What can I do to fix that?

Comment: "I tried to paste the same code on other page." Which bit code are you referring to here? Can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: i copy layout.tsx and page.tsx to other dir called contacts...

Comment: I solve it, the tag <nav> canot be used inside <html> tag, i move <nav> to inside body and works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a fix HTML Code.

In layout.tsx:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <body className={inter.className}>
    <nav className="bg-blue-500 text-white h-12 flex items-center justify-center gap-12">
      {navigation.map((navItem) => (
        <Link key={navItem.title} href={navItem.path}>
          <div>{navItem.title}</div>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </nav>
    {children}
  </body>
</html>
```

This is because the code that makes up the 'body' must be entered. This is one of the errors that occur for this reason.

Comment: This answer could be improved if you also explained what you did and why.

Comment: It's for a simple reason. The code that makes up the 'body' must be entered. This is one of the errors that occur for this reason.

Comment: By [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76675339/edit) (changing) your answer, not in comments (they may be removed at any time). (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)